# Get elements containing text from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, contains

I want to search all the elements containing any string in the array.
For example 
I have following list of items

```
<ul>
    <li>cricket bat</li>
    <li>tennis ball</li>
    <li>golf ball</li>
    <li>hockey stick</li>
</ul>
```

and this array

```
var arr = ['bat', 'ball'];
```

It should select all the elements having text bat and ball. How can I achieve this using jquery or javascript.

This is what I was trying

```
filter = 'bat ball';
var lis = row('UL li');
var flag = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var name = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
    if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [:contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

I think you meant either one of those values, in that case

```js
var arr = ['bat', 'ball'];

var selectors = arr.map(function(val) {
  return ':contains(' + val + ')'
});
var $lis = $('ul li').filter(selectors.join());

$lis.css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>cricket bat</li>
  <li>tennis ball</li>
  <li>golf ball</li>
  <li>hockey stick</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I get only those list items which are having all the string of the array in any order? for example 'bat ball' or 'ball bat' or 'hockey bat and cricket ball'

Comment: @Twix `var $lis = $('ul li').filter(selectors.join(''));`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector:

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('li:contains("bat"), li:contains("ball")')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y8hu96gh/)

Comment: value of array may be changed it can be 100 words to 1 word. How can I use this?

Comment: @Twix Add the each element in array as `,` separated as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.filter()`, `.match()`

```js
var arr = ["bat", "ball"];

var res = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("li")
          , function(el, index) {
              return el.textContent.match(new RegExp(arr.join("|"))) !== null
          });
  
console.log(res);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>cricket bat</li>
    <li>tennis ball</li>
    <li>golf ball</li>
    <li>hockey stick</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perhaps there is [not enough jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(["bat", "ball"], function (i,val) {
    if ($("ul li:contains(" + val + ")").length) {
        $("ul li:contains(" + val + ")").css('color', 'red')
    }
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t8gbew46/)**