# How to delete rows from table that are unequal to a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that looks like this

```
R1C1     R1C2     R1C3
R2C1     R2C2     R2C3
R3C1     R3C2     R3C3
```

and a function that removes a row from the table when a particular cell value is found. That works fine, see function code below where the result is that row 1 and 3 get deleted

However, when I want to do the opposite - keep only the rows that contain the specified cell values by changing the comparison operator from 0 to -1 (what indexOf() returns if it doesn't find the string), the function deletes all rows and not row 2 as I expected.

Can anyone shed some light on this and provide me with a solution on how to accomplish what I want?

Here is the function code:

```
function doFunction() {

let array = ['R3C2','R1C3'];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var removeRowWithCell = array[i];

    // change the comparison below to === -1 and it deletes all rows

    $('td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf(removeRowWithCell) === 0;
    }).closest('tr').remove();

   }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns position from the array. If it is `-1` it means there is no match but if you specify `0` you are expecting as a very first element. In your case I believe you need `return $(this).text().indexOf(removeRowWithCell) !== -1` to use.

Comment: Find all the rows that match any of the elements in your array, then delete them. See [Get elements containing text from array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972778/215552).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what I want to do is to remove all the elements that do NOT match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition with === -1 translates to "rows which has at least one cell which does not equal either 'R3C2' or 'R1C3'".

With this in mind (only 1st cell of each row compared with 1st item from the array "R3C2" analysis):

- 1st row cell R1C1: "R1C1".indexOf("R3C2") is -1 => cell is selected, row is removed
- 2nd row cell R2C1: "R2C1".indexOf("R3C2") is -1 => cell is selected, row is removed
- 3rd row cell R3C1: "R2C1".indexOf("R3C2") is -1 => cell is selected, row is removed

Hence you end up with all your rows removed

Your function to keep rows containing some value from the array should look like:

```
function doFunction() {
    let array = ['R3C2','R1C3'];

    var rows = $('tr');

    for(var k = 0; k < rows.length; k++) {
        var currentRow = $(rows[k]);
        var columns = currentRow.find('td');
        var shouldKeepRow = false;  
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var removeRowWithCell = array[i];

            // Check if at least one column on this row contains this value
            shouldKeepRow = columns.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().indexOf(removeRowWithCell) === 0;
            }).length > 0;

            if (shouldKeepRow) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!shouldKeepRow) {
            currentRow.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VanillaJS version. Perhaps this is what you want.

```js
let table = document.querySelector("table"),
    tBody = table.tBodies[0];
    
let array = ['R3C2','R1C3'];

Array.from(tBody.rows).forEach(function(row){
let contains = false;
  for(let cell of row.cells){
    if(array.indexOf(cell.innerText) !== -1){
      contains = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!contains){
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);  
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>R1C1</td>
   <td>R1C2</td>
   <td>R1C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>R2C1</td>
   <td>R2C2</td>
   <td>R2C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>R3C1</td>
   <td>R3C2</td>
   <td>R3C3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you first look for `R3C2` and remove everything else, next time you go trough you for-loop you search for `R1C3` but only `R3C2` exists and that will be removed.

Comment: that sounds logical for more than 1 criteria, but even if I reduce the array to only 1 element, say R1C3, it removes all rows and not row 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easier with jQuery.inArray

```
function doFunction() {
    let array = ['R3C2','R1C3'];
    var rows = $('tr');

    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var cells = $(rows[j]).children('td').map(function() { return $(this).text(); });     

            if($.inArray(array[i], cells) === -1){
                $(rows[j]).remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```